# Remove elements or attributes from input file which are defined in external XML file

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-1.0

I want to maintain an external XML file in which I will keep those elements/attributes which should be removed from an input file. So, whenever a new element/attribute need to be removed, I will just add that in my external XML file.

I created an XSLT which is removing an element by matching names in an incoming file with my external file. Problem is, this is not matching all the elements, only first occurrence is getting removed. Elements/attributes which I want to remove those can come anywhere in an input file.

My XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <!-- @=attribuutti -->
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="node()[name() = name(document('TagsDB.xml')/INVOICE_CENTER/ElementsToRemove/*)]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input.XML

```
<INVOICE_CENTER>
    <CONTENT_FRAME>
        <Test1>123</Test1>
        <INVOICES>
            <INVOICE>
                <HEADER>
                    <PROCESS_CODE>00</PROCESS_CODE>
                </HEADER>
                <ROWS>
                    <ROW>
                        <ROW_NUMBER>0</ROW_NUMBER>
                        <Test2>12345</Test2>
                    </ROW>
                </ROWS>
            </INVOICE>
        </INVOICES>
    </CONTENT_FRAME>
</INVOICE_CENTER>
```

My External file (TagsDB.xml) where I mentioned element/attribute which should be removed:

```
<INVOICE_CENTER>
    <ElementsToRemove>
        <Test1/>
        <Test2/>
    </ElementsToRemove>
    <AttributesToRemove Att1="" Att2=""/>
</INVOICE_CENTER>
```

Expected result is:

```
<INVOICE_CENTER>
    <CONTENT_FRAME>
        <INVOICES>
            <INVOICE>
                <HEADER>
                    <PROCESS_CODE>00</PROCESS_CODE>
                </HEADER>
                <ROWS>
                    <ROW>
                        <ROW_NUMBER>0</ROW_NUMBER>
                        </ROW>
                </ROWS>
            </INVOICE>
        </INVOICES>
    </CONTENT_FRAME>
</INVOICE_CENTER>
```

So, Test1 and Test2 should be removed from the XML because those are defined in my external XML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `name()` function returns the name of the **first** node in the selected node-set. You need to formulate your condition as:

> if the external document does not contain an element whose name is equal to the name of this element

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:if test="not(document('TagsDB.xml')/INVOICE_CENTER/ElementsToRemove/*[name()=name(current())])">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

To handle attributes too, you can do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:if test="not(document('TagsDB.xml')/INVOICE_CENTER/ElementsToRemove/*[name()=name(current())])">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:if test="not(document('TagsDB.xml')/INVOICE_CENTER/AttributesToRemove/@*[name()=name(current())])">
        <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. I am getting an error that 'It is an error to use the current() function in a pattern'.

Comment: Oops. Sorry about that - I tested with a more tolerant processor. Try the edited version.

Comment: That is perfect! It worked. Thank you so much. I really appreciate it.

Comment: One more thing, in the similar way, can I remove attributes also?

Comment: Yes - see the addition to my answer.